# How to store large JSON 50Gb+ file in Databricks?

Tags: json, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm fairly new to this, but I have a large JSON file which I uploaded to Azure ADLSv2 and connected it with Azure Databricks. I've managed to read the file into a dataframe and now I was thinking of saving it to a delta table to speed up reads later on, so I don't have to read the entire file again just to get it into memory.

My question is, is it enough to just run the following command:

`df.write.format('delta').save('/mnt/data/delta/silver/actual_total_track')`

Or is it best practice to partition the saved data? Would there be any difference in performance?

The JSON is nested and the `df.printSchema` shows it is 4 levels deep.

Answer (score 0):

You can  improve performance of Delta Lake using partition pruning.

This [article](https://kb.databricks.com/delta/delta-merge-into.html) explains how to trigger partition pruning in Delta Lake MERGE INTO queries from Databricks.

Partition pruning is an optimization technique to limit the number of partitions that are inspected by a query.

If you don’t partition the underlying data and use it appropriately, query performance can be severely impacted.

Comment: I really can't inspect my data, so I don't know what to partition it by.